# Pull request on bitbucket isn't triggering a build on bamboo

Tags: git, bitbucket, bamboo, bitbucket-server

I've been trying to set things up to trigger a build for a pull request.

Our setup is as follows:

- Bamboo 6.5.0 local server
- Bitbucket 4.11.2 using git, local server
- The plan repository is linked with the **master** branch
- I've got a "Bitbucket Server repository triggered" trigger defined looking at the linked repo
- My build plan is based on the linked repo and has a manual branch setup for **develop**
- On the "Branches" tab of the build plan I've get "Create Plan When pull request is created"  and triggers "same as in parent plan"

The 2 servers are linked. I can see build results for master and develop on bitbucket, and I can see the commits listed in the build results. Also on the "branchStatus" page the pull request branch is listed.

I've tried pull requests from feature branches named with "feature/*" and "feature-*" and pull requests to both **develop** and **master**

Regardless of this I never get the pull request build happening.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the issue is that the connections between bitbucket and bamboo weren't configured correctly. We got some guidance from [Atlassian](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bamboo-questions/How-to-workout-why-pull-request-git-on-bitbucket-isn-t/qaq-p/875923) but are still working through the issues. Initially it was network configuration from bitbucket to bamboo

I'll update here later, but the ultimate resolution is hoped to be deleting and recreating the link.